# Error while deploying package to catalog

Tags: sql-server, ssis, deployment, catalogs

I am getting below error while deploying package to SSIS catalog on the last step, I am sysadmin and have access to the below views. Can someone help please. Let me know if you need more info. Any help is appreciated

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'database_principals',
>   database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. (Microsoft SQL Server,
>   Error: 229)

Comment: Deploying how? Are you using the package deployment model (msdb) or project deployment model (SSISDB). Is the admin account a windows domain account or a SQL Server admin account?

Comment: yes its a windows account, i am deploying from data tools 2010 using projext deployment

Comment: Hmmmm, I was expecting to see project deployment model but not the windows account. Behind the covers, the methods in the SSISDB catalog do all sorts of impersonation during the deployment which goes sideways if you try to use a SQL Server account for the deploys. Still smells permission like but if you're sa, it can't be...

Comment: Are you able to deploy any other SSIS packages?  Were you ever able to deploy in the past?  Try creating the simplest possible package, and then deploy it.  When solving problems, particularly security-related, I like to establish a baseline of functionality: find what does work, and then compare that to what doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may occur if the user has Deny privilege on the target objects as well. Please check the permissions settings on the target database.

You should remove this roles from your account.

- db_denydatareader
- db_denydatawriter